# EntityNotFoundException for a newly associated entity

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa, persistence

i do have DEVICE entity which has an association with PROPERTIES entity as defined below,

```
@OneToOne(cascade = { CascadeType.ALL }, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval = true)
private Properties properties;
```

where PROPERTIES entity has id as follow,

```
@Id
@Column(name=ID)
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;
```

I have two thread acting parallel,

Thread-1 --> For DEVICE-1 it will try to get the PROPERTIES entity. It came as null(no property defined).
Hence it will create the new PROPERTIES-1 and add to DEVICE-1 entity.

Thread-2 --> Tries to delete the DEVICE-1. During deleting, it throws below exception.

```
javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: Unable to find com.entity.properties with id 3
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$JpaEntityNotFoundDelegate.handleEntityNotFound(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:181)
    at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.checkTargetState(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:262)
    at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.initialize(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:176)
    at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.getImplementation(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:286)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.StatefulPersistenceContext.unproxyAndReassociate(StatefulPersistenceContext.java:603)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultDeleteEventListener.onDelete(DefaultDeleteEventListener.java:89)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireDelete(SessionImpl.java:929)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.delete(SessionImpl.java:906)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.CascadingActions$1.cascade(CascadingActions.java:74)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeToOne(Cascade.java:350)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:293)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:161)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:118)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultDeleteEventListener.cascadeAfterDelete(DefaultDeleteEventListener.java:376)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultDeleteEventListener.deleteEntity(DefaultDeleteEventListener.java:312)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultDeleteEventListener.onDelete(DefaultDeleteEventListener.java:160)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultDeleteEventListener.onDelete(DefaultDeleteEventListener.java:73)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireDelete(SessionImpl.java:920)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.delete(SessionImpl.java:896)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.remove(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1214)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)[:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)[:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)[:1.8.0_131]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)[:1.8.0_131]
    at org.apache.aries.jpa.support.osgi.impl.EmProxy.invoke(EmProxy.java:43)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy130.remove(Unknown Source)
    at Proxyc164ca4b_578b_459f_ace4_b5791bab5274.remove(Unknown Source)
```

This issue seen when these two threads are executed at same time with some milliseconds difference. Kindly help me to understand the possibility/cause of this error.

Comment: As we can not predict Thread's behavior/output, there is possibility that Thread-2 is getting executed before Thread-1 which does not find required PROPERTIES entity and throws exception. Try executing threads multiple times and see if it works sometimes.

Comment: This issue seen when these two threads are executed at same time with some milliseconds difference.

Here thread-2(delete thread) is throwing the exception. If thread-1(adding property entity) is not completed then how come thread-2 throws error with id details.

Comment: @Vlad Mihalcea - can you please check this

Answer (score 0):

After little bit analyze i could see that the hibernate is creating a proxy for PROPERTIES entity with proper id. Then during the delete process it is trying to load the actual entity from the session. Where this entity is not found in the session which lead to EntityNotFoundException.

Use FetchType.EAGER will load the actual entity and avoid this exception.

Hibernate version: 4.3.6.Final

Even the changing the isolation level from REPEATABLE READ to READ COMMITTED also solved the problem.
But as a solution we have applied a retry mechanism for EntityNotFoundException.